# Get value from specific MySql row

Tags: php, mysql

On my website, a user's background URL is stored with their data in a database. I need to get this value and store it in a variable.
However, I am having trouble doing so, the code I have right now gives me an error but doesnt tell me what the error is.

My code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'config.php';
$pin = $_COOKIE["UID"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * from users where pin ='$pin'";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    $bg_url = $row[bg_url];
} else {

    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

echo $bg_url;

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You don't ask for the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * from users where pin ='$pin'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Actually yes, the John's answer is correct, you're not using the return values properly, but you are neither accesing the variables properly, for example, I don't see where $row comes from. Try this and change it for array mode if you need to. I'm not very used to mysqli_* API, because I use PDO mostly.

```
if ($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $bg_url = $row->bg_url;
    }
} else {

    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

echo $bg_url;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could be helpful